# How to read http post request data as JSON in MVC home controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a home controller method below which is invoked from a http post request. I need to read the request data and send it to the view. Is there a way to look at the raw data without creating parameters in the SaveResponse() ?
Thanks for any suggestions.

```
 public ActionResult SaveResponse()
    {
        //Read the http post request body as json and send it to view
        //HttpContext.Request.RequestContext

        return View("CallbackView");
    }
```

The request body will be in JSON format.

```
{
   "customers":
  {
    "firstName": "Test”,
    "lastName": “Lastname”,
    "fullAddress": 
    {
        "streetAddress": "123 springs lane",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": 10021
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check my answer. If it doesn't work please provide front-end code making a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by reading `Request.InputStream`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveResponse()
{
    string json;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
    {
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return View("CallbackView");
}
```

or you can accept `string` parameter and model binder will do everything for you, but you need to pass data as a string via `json` parameter. Some of available options

- Set `Content-Type: application/json` and payload like `{"json": "{id:44}"}`
- Set `Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded` and payload like `json={id:44}`

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveResponse(string json)
{
    return View("CallbackView");
}
```

Comment: nice work showcasing the use the StreamReader, however could you please expand further what you mean by "pass data as json={json string}?

I figured you mean Content-Type:application/JSON but still wasn't able to bind the body to the string json parameter.